# Is it possible to make a pickaxe in Minecraft which breaks certain blocks at a certain location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a parkour map and my construction site fence is made out of iron bars and I want to make a pickaxe which the player could use inside the construction site but couldn't break the fence. I want to make an obstacle inside the construction site out of iron bars which could be broken with an iron pickaxe that can break iron bars inside the construction site, but not outside of it.

Comment: As I understand from no responses, it's impossible to make that kind of pickaxe.

Comment: it takes more than 2 hours to get a good reply usually

Comment: Could we please get a bit more information on what you wish to accomplish? For example, the size of the obstacle, the size of the fence, does the player have to place any blocks? And how familiar are you with commands?

Comment: Oh, and should this work with multiplayer?

Comment: I'm making this map for singleplayer, the obstacle is just a 5x4 iron bars wall and the construction size is about 75x125, the player doesn't have to place any blocks he just needs to break the obstacle, but not the construction site's fence. I know commands quite a bit but not that good at it.

Comment: I counted the exact size of the construction size: 78x108.

Comment: Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: I were working many hours with the `/data` command and was close to giving up, but then I randomly stumbled on `/replaceitem` with youtube recommendations and came up with a solution. I hope my answer suits your needs.

Comment: An easy solution would be using a specific block type in the desired location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with 2 repeating command blocks.
First command gives the closest player the item:

```
give @p minecraft:iron_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["iron_bars"],tag:1}
```

The first command executes only if a player is inside the area in which the pickaxe should work, that's what is determined in the x=... y=... z=... as well as dx=... dy=... dz=...

x y z is the cords and dx dy dz is the size (x=10 and dx=2 would put the starting x at 10 and the end at 12). This is the area in which the obstacle is in, don't make it too small so the player needs to hug the iron bars to destroy them, but not too big so they can reach unwanted iron bars.

The command replaces the player's held item only if the item is a pickaxe and has the tag `tag:1`. The tag is necessary so the command doesn't continuously give the player a new pickaxe. Then the command `/replaceitem` replaces the held item with a pickaxe that can break iron bars.

This command needs to be in a repeating command block:

```
execute if entity @a[x=-12,y=56,z=8,dx=-7,dy=1,dz=-2] as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:
{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",tag:{tag:1}}}] if entity @s 
run replaceitem entity @s weapon.mainhand iron_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["iron_bars"]}
```

The next command basically does everything opposite of the first command. It only runs for players that aren't in the specified area (make sure you enter the same x y z and dx dy dz in both commands), it then tests for a held pickaxe that can break iron bars and lastly runs the command `/replaceitem` and gives the player a normal pickaxe with the tag `tag:1`.

This one does need to be in a repeating command block as well:

```
execute unless entity @a[x=-12,y=56,z=8,dx=-7,dy=1,dz=-2] 
as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",tag:
{CanDestroy:["iron_bars"]}}}] if entity @s run replaceitem 
entity @s weapon.mainhand iron_pickaxe{tag:1}
```

The commands don't affect a player that doesn't have the special pickaxe, so you can create different ones later on with different tags.

**Important note**

`/replaceitem` will be removed in 1.17 and replaced with `/item`. However, you can easily convert to the new command, instead of:

`/replaceitem entity @s weapon.mainhand iron_pickaxe{tag:1}`

it will be:

`/item entity @s weapon.mainhand replace iron_pickaxe{tag:1}`

Comment: This is pretty cool thanks for your help, but I want to make it so that the player collects different tools around the city from chest (they would be regular tools, they couldn't break anything), and when the player enters a certain area how to replace their regular tools with the ones that can break certain blocks. Could you type the command that when you enter that certain area it replaces your tools with the ones that break those blocks. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, you just need to remove the `,tag:{tag:1}` in this command
`execute if entity @a[x=-12,y=56,z=8,dx=-7,dy=1,dz=-2] as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:
{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",tag:{tag:1}}}] if entity @s 
run replaceitem entity @s weapon.mainhand iron_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["iron_bars"]}`

Comment: Thanks a lot man, really helped me out